# Do different compilers produce different machine code file formats for Windows?

Tags: windows, compile, gcc, c++

Under Windows, if someone compiled a C++ source code with gcc, would the output file formats and extensions be different from other C++ compilers?

And are the output files extensions and formats of C++ compilers different from the output of C# compilers? Or can you choose whatever output files you want?

Comment: What do you mean file format? As in *.exe or as in solution packages like .cpp?

Comment: Yes; The machine code generated would be slightly different but it would perform the exact same method. Each compiler will do optimization in a different way. You cannot compare output of the C# compiler to the output of GCC or the VC++ compiler.  The outputs can't even be compared they are entirely different.  **This doesn't seem like a real question.**

Comment: This is really unclear and covers way too big of a scope (compilers, linkers, assemblers, executable formats...) - a language spec only says what it should *do*, not *how to do it*, which is what a compiler *exists* for in the first place.

Comment: @Breakthrough see the [C++ ABI](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/) this question really is asking about it.

Comment: Next time before asking a question please try to be as specific as possible and stick around in the first few minutes after posting. You've got great answers here but they don't answer what you originally intended. Now I wouldn't delete the question because you've got four people who took the time to respond to you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is beyond recovery. The initial question led to great answers that do not line up with the posters intended message/ question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different types of files involved.

A (traditional) compiler first produces an "object file", which contains the instructions corresponding to the .c (etc) file that was the input to the compiler.  This file is "relocatable" and "linkable", meaning it does not assume it's loaded at a specific address, and it contains only "symbolic" (ie, name string) references to other code that it calls.

The "object file" is combined with other object files using a "linker" (or "link-loader" or "linkage editor") which produces an "executable" file that had all the references between separate object files "resolved" and at least some of the "relocation" (address assignment) done.

The executable file is then processed by a "loader" to copy the file into executable RAM and prepare it to run.  The "loader" would do any necessary final "relocation", would locate the entry point of the executable, etc.

There may also be "library file" which is a kind of dictionary of "object files" that can be used to "resolve" references from other object files.  And there also may be a "module" or some such (name varies by platform) which is a pre-linked subset of object modules.

Each of these can potentially have several different formats.  Eg, with original DOS/Windows there was a COM file format and an EXE file format, both of which were "executable" files, ready to be loaded.  And I have heard of systems that had multiple "object file" formats, though I can't remember any off-hand.  It's not that hard to make a linker, say, examine it's incoming "object files" and handle them differently based on the discovered type.  (But I don't know if any current Windows tools do this.)

Note that C# and Java (and several historical languages such as UCSD Pascal) are different, since they produce "bytecode" files designed to be interpreted rather than linked, loaded, and executed.

Answer (score 0):

The file format refers to the file organization. Windows expects binary executable files to have some kind of format. It doesn't matter the language they were compiled from.

Generally speaking there is more than one machine code for the same source code of any given language. So different compilers are likely to create different binary files from the same source code. But they are going to do exactly the same thing. In fact one given compiler could produce different binary files from the same source, if you change the code optimization options or other parameters.

C# compilers will certainly create different binaries than C++ compilers for an equivalent source code.

Answer (score 0):

> If someone compiled a c++ source code by gcc compiler , will the output files formats be different from other c++ compilers outputs ?

Probably.  There's many ways to translate C++ code into machine language, especially on x86/amd64 which has a broad array of instructions that can be combined in many ways, and unless the compilers share the same code themselves they are probably not doing this the same exact way.  Some simple stuff may coincide, like `switch` statements and what not.

If by "file format" you mean executable format (e.g. Windows Portable Executable format), any *compiler* would have to, in order to generate something you could run.

> And are the output files formats of c++ compilers different from the output of c# compilers ? , or you can choose whatever output files you want ?

Substantially, as C# is part of .NET and compiles to CIL, not native code.  I'm not entirely sure if Visual C++ lets you select between compiling to native or CIL.  I believe C# only lets you compile to CIL.  I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Oy, complex question...

**This first part, about whether C++ can match up to C++**

All this assumes the same chip/abi. If we don't have that match, we won't be compatible in any way at all. We need 32 bit x86 code matching 32 bit x86 code, or 64 bit AMD64 code matching with AMD64 code.

1) For C (we start simple, talk about C++ later) objects, the output for different compilers is compatible with other compilers. There's something called the chip [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), which keeps things consistent. We match how we set up the stack, how we set up the registers, etc. Very early on, there was some incompatibility because of symbol length, but that's been settled for Many years.

This works because C is relatively simple.  What do we have to synch up? function names, and function calls. That's all within the ABI

2) for C++, we have a lot of knobs to adjust. How do we lay out an object? How/when do we call static constructors/destructors? How do we lay out an object for inheritance? Or multiple inheritance? Virtual functions?  Even "simple" things like how do we "mangle" function names (how do we rename the symbol for functions to have argument types in the symbol name). We have a LOT of decisions to make here, a lot of different paths we *could* go down.

In the beginning, C++ compiler vendors did what they thought best was here. That can be read: they did whatever they wanted and cared nada for compatibility, so there was none.  Later they realized this made it impossible to sell libraries easily - you needed to have a C++ library compiled for EVERY compiler version (or at least a big subset of versions).

Eventually they came up with the [Standard C++ ABI](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/).  This allowed code from multiple compilers to come together. Its a tighter list of layouts and names and such to make sure the code can call each other properly.

Yay! All modern compilers on the standard! Everything done! Right?

Not really.... First, if you're moving to a new ABI, it means you're not compatible with the old ABI. Second, you're coding to a spec, but no guarantee that you got it right. In the beginning of G++ trying to match with the spec, they got it wrong a few times.

**So, summarizing for C++:**

There is a spec that should make it that makes C++ code compatible across compilers. but it depends on whether the compilers coded to the spec, and whether they got the spec right. For modern compilers (anything in the last 5 years) this should be true.

**Now, about C++ and C#....**

C++ is meant to run on the chip. Directly on X86, or AMD64, whatever. As such, it has opcodes for these specific chips. The chip reads a number, realizes what command it represents, and does what it asks it to.

C# is meant to run on a virtual machine, called the CLI.  As such, it has different commands, and the numbers are not the same. It's like making a person who knows just english read instructions for a car tune-up in French. It just won't work.

Comment: Have you read the update by the OP saying it's about file extensions only?